# Plot multiple line graph from Pandas into Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a multi line-graph plot from a pandas dataframe using seaborn. Below is a .csv of the of the data and the desired plot. In excel I simply selected the whole dataset and swapped the axis. Technically there are 110 lines (rows) on this, but many aren't visible because they only contain 0's.

[image: Multi-line plot with 16 bins]

This is my code:

```
individual_burst_data = {'nb001':nb001, 'nb002':nb002, 'nb003':nb003, 'nb004':nb004, 'nb005':nb005, 'nb006':nb006, 'nb007':nb007, 'nb008':nb008, 'nb009':nb009, 'nb010':nb010, 'nb011':nb011, 'nb012':nb012, 'nb013':nb013, 'nb015':nb015, 'nb016':nb016 }
ibd_panda_conv = pd.DataFrame(individual_burst_data)

sns.lineplot(data = ibd_panda_conv, x = individual_burst_data, y =ibd_panda_conv)
```

Other sources seem to only extract one column, whereas I need all the columns.

I tried to create an index for the y-axis

```
index_data = list(range(0,len(individual_burst_data)))
```

but this didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seaborn `lineplot()` [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) says:

> Passing the entire wide-form dataset to `data` plots a separate line for each column

Since you want a line for each row instead, you need to transpose your dataframe, so try this:

```py
sns.lineplot(data=ibd_panda_conv.T, dashes=False)
```